# Selenium + Python - Checking image via execute_script

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify if a image is shown on page with selenium in python.
For example lets check logo in left upper corner of the https://openweathermap.org/ page.
I use `execute_script` and  my code is:

```
def test_image(driver):
    driver.get('https://openweathermap.org/')
    time.sleep(10)
    image = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#first-level-nav > li.logo > a > img")
    print(image)
    print(driver.execute_script("return (typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth!=\"undefined\");", image))
    print(driver.execute_script("return (typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth>0);", image))
    print(driver.execute_script("return (arguments[0].naturalWidth);", image))
```

And I got this results:

```
True
False
431
```

Why `typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth>0` is `False` when `arguments[0].naturalWidth` is `431`? And image rendered correctly on the page.

**UPDATE: Correct code is:**

`print(driver.execute_script("return (arguments[0].naturalWidth>0);", image))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `typeof` operator takes precedence over `>`.

```
typeof 431     === "number"
"number"   > 0 === false
typeof 431 > 0 === false
```